# Debug files not being updated atomically (possible PDF.js browser issue)

Tags: php, linux

I'm using webkithtmltopdf to generate PDFs & wish to overwrite any existing files.

I'm unsure if this guarantees atomic updates, or if we'll be using a different PDF tool one day, so I have wrapped it in some PHP code which uses a temp file. Once the temp file is created, I use PHP's rename() function to overwrite the actual file.

I have ensured that the temp file & the output file exist on the same partition, however when I run my script I sometimes get "PDF file could not be displayed" type of messages from the browser if I request the PDF at the exact instant its being overwritten.

How could I attempt to debug this? I do not see any errors in the Apache error log. I see "200" and "206" requests in the access logs. I'm not sure what I'm looking for on the Content-Length, or how pdf.js works together with the server.

Code looks like this:

```
$output = sprintf(__DIR__."/pdfs/%s.pdf", $id);
$tmpOutput = $output . '.tmp';
$cmd = 'wkhtmltopdf '. escapeshellarg($url) . ' ' . escapeshellarg($tmpOutput);

exec($cmd);
chmod($tmpOutput, 0777);
rename($tmpOutput, $output);
chmod($output, 0777);
```

Its worth mentioning, I am using chmod to workaround the fact I'm running this in a gearman worker, run by supervisor, which was started by root. If this were a permission problem, I'd expect an error stating that in the Apache error log, but theres not - and I'd also expect a 403 status code or the like, but all I see is 200 or 206 in the logs.

Comment: atomically? what does that mean, like atoms and stuff?

Comment: @meda like changing a variable without other threads changing it

Comment: atomically means that at any point in time, any process reading that path should get a fully formed pdf file. It should not get a blank or partial file as a consequence of reading it at the exact instant that its being updated. Either it gets the old file, or the new file.

Comment: @meda done in one step, without anything that could happen in the meantime, so preventing race conditions - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability

Comment: if you access file by script, script could check whole file is there before severing it ? If it's not it could be safe for it to just sleep a second and try again ? with a max number of sleep periods of course

Comment: Your code looks ok, if anything other isn't tampering with that pdf file, apache should have it always available. Most pdf viewers get the file in chunks (hence http `206` response), so maybe they get first half from the old file and another part from the newly generated one...

Comment: @meda i to did not know the term untill i read it here on S.O last year - we did not all do comp sci degrees

Comment: @Marki555 that's smart thinking & probably whats happening. Maybe I need to rethink overwriting the files in the first place then?

Comment: @Dagon yes thats another good workaround. I'd prefer to avoid a script if possible though, so we can switch to S3 later on... but might just work in the meantime.

Comment: debug to pdf seems odd, pdf is a rather poor format.

Comment: Check if apache is sending the `ETag` for your pdf file (for example with `wget -S`. If yes, then web browser should send `If-Match` header with its partial request, so that apache can return `412` when the file changes in the meantime.

Comment: It is sending the ETag. When I request the PDF in Chrome, devtools shows a single 200 request/response. but Apache shows 3 responses each with 206 status code, with 3 differing byte counts (33114, 1439259, 1471971) which does not match the byte count of the PDF shown by wget (1471673).

Sometimes I get the 206 responses in the log. Sometimes 200. I can't find any rhyme or reason why it changes.

Comment: My PDFs are a single page. As such I turned off range requests:

<Files *.pdf>
    Header set Accept-Ranges none
</Files>

I fill up the PDF queue & reload the PDF in the browser. I still get occasional messages saying "This PDF May not be displayed correctly" with a blank white PDF page below. The access log now always show "200 ok" and shows the correct Content-Length, that is invariant - but the symptoms still occur, seemingly at random. I think this final symptoms can be solved in my code (The temp file is not unique across instances of my worker).

Comment: @Marki555 Between disabling range requests, and fixing the temp file to be random, the issue seems fixed. If you want to write up an answer I'll gladly mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most PDF readers read PDF files from net in chunks, that means in several HTTP requests using the `Range` header (specifying which byte range from the file it wants, e.g. 1000-5000, so byte count 4000). Webserver replies with HTTP `206 Partial Content` response code. If you change the PDF file between these partial requests, PDF reader will receive corrupted file (part from the old file, part from new file).

HTTP protocol should prevent it - On first request PDF reader should receive also `ETAg` header, which is unique and changes if the file in changed. On subsequent requests the PDF reader should send `If-Match` header, so that webserver can inform it if the file is still the same. But sometimes this doesn't work. You can disable `Range` requests within apache configuration (or `.htaccess` file) with this:

```
<Files *.pdf>
  Header set Accept-Ranges none
</Files>
```

Also make sure that your temp file is always unique, so that no 2 PHP processes will write to the same temp filename at the same time.